# Any way to simplify data.frame in the nested list for ease of manipulation?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I need to evaluate data.frame in the list with threshold value, intend to get new group of data.frame that needed to be exported as `csv` files. However, after I classify each data.frame with given threshold, result becomes nested list instead. Perhaps, I have to manipulate these resulted nested list as list of data.frame, then loop over the data.frame list to export them as `csv` files. I used `reshape2` to melt the resulted nested list, but don't know how to group them by needs and export them in desired way. Can any one point me easier way to manipulate nested list to make data.frame list ? How can I make this happen ? Is there any efficient way to get this done ? Thanks a lot :)

This is the reproducible input data.frame list:

```
myList <- list(
    hotan = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=25), end=seq(4, by=6, len=25), pos.score=sample(30, 25)),
    aksu = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=30), end=seq(6, by=9, len=30), pos.score=sample(45, 30)),
    korla = data.frame( begin=seq(6, by=8, len=45), end=seq(11, by=8, len=45), pos.score=sample(52, 45))
)
```

I need to evaluate each data.frame with threshold, which result in nested list like this :

```
rslt <- lapply(myList, function(x) {
    res <- split(x, ifelse(x$pos.score >=18, "good","bad"))
})
```

I tried to use `melt` to remove nested list structure :

```
library(reshape2)
melt(rslt)
```

perhaps, getting out of nested list first, cast `rslt` to list of data.frame, then using `lapply` to export each as `csv` files. Any idea please ?

**Edit** :

I know the general way to deal with nested list by using `unlist`, perhaps `data.table` or `dplyr` provides better function to treat this sort of problem. I want to learn with new solution. Thanks

I am trying to achieve this data.frame list :

```
hotan.good
hotan.bad
aksu.good
aksu.bad
korla.good
korla.bad
```

How can I achieve desired data.frame list that needed to be exported as `csv` file ? How can I manipulate `rslt` ?

Comment: `unlist(rslt, recursive = FALSE) `

Comment: @Apom I know this, I am looking for something interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I continue @MarkusN' solution (thanks for his help) :

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- bind_rows(myList, .id="sample") %>% 
    mutate(threshold = ifelse(pos.score >=18, "good", "bad")) %>%
    split(list(.$threshold,.$sample))
mapply(write.csv, DF, paste0(getwd(), names(DF), ".csv"))
```

In this way, exporting data.frame in the nested list can be much easier and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use a list of dataframes? You can easily put all data in one dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
df = bind_rows(myList, .id="name")
# new Variable threshold
df %>% mutate(threshold = ifelse(pos.score >=18, "good", "bad"))
```

now you can filter and select your data within this dataframe (or even split it into a list of dataframes.)

Comment: @Dan You can evaluate subsets of a single data.frame in chunks with `group_by` from dplyr or `by=` from data.table. Unless you have some plan for parallel processing that you know will outperform these, I'd say stick with a single object. (Replying to a disappearing comment...)

Answer (score 1):

Write `hotan.good.csv`, `hotan.bad.csv`, `aksu.good.csv`,... to existing `./out/` folder:

```
library(magrittr)
l <- unlist(rslt, recursive = FALSE)
l %>% 
  names() %>% 
  lapply(FUN = function(f) write.csv(l[[f]], paste0("out/", f, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)) %>% 
  invisible()
```